# I want to enable datepicker through select box in php

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ved_emp_main_details_calender_css.css">
<script src="../script/calender_script/ved_emp_main_details_date_script.js"></script>
<script src="../script/calender_script/ved_emp_compoff_date_jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() 
{
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,yearRange: '1920:2040'});
});



<td>
    <div class="label" nowrap><label><?php echo COLCTED;?></label></div> 
</td>
<td>
    <div class="form-fields">
    <div class="input">
    <select name="iCollected">
        <option  selected value="-1"><?php echo CHOOSE;?></option>
        <option value="1"><?php echo YES;?></option>
        <option value="0"><?php echo NO;?></option>
    </select> 
    </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

I want to pass through date picker function when yes is selected in select box. I want to enable date picker only when yes is selected or else date picker should be disabled

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
$(function() 
{
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,yearRange: '1920:2040'});

    $('select[name="iCollected"]').change(function(){
       if($(this).val() == "1")
       {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('enable');;
       }
       else
       {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('disable');
       }
    }).trigger('change'); //trigger change event on page load.
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf18hbfj/)